# How to use placeholders in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
df['Variable Name']=df['Variable Name'].replace(' 15 °',' at 15 °', regex=True)
df['Variable Name']=df['Variable Name'].replace(' at at 15 °',' at 15 °', regex=True)
df['Variable Name']=df['Variable Name'].replace(' 0 °',' at 0 °', regex=True)
df['Variable Name']=df['Variable Name'].replace(' at at 0 °',' at 0 °', regex=True)
df['Variable Name']=df['Variable Name'].replace(' 5 °',' at 5 °', regex=True)
df['Variable Name']=df['Variable Name'].replace(' at at 5 °',' at 5 °', regex=True)
```

And would like to know how to shorten it. 
I tried a for loop:

```
for x in range(0,15,5):
    df['Variable Name']=df['Variable Name'].replace(' %s °',' at %s °', x, regex=True)
    df['Variable Name']=df['Variable Name'].replace(' at at %s °',' at %s °', x, regex=True)
```

But I get the error message:

```
ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type int.
```

What's a better way to do it?

Edit: Added snippet

```
Variable Name                          Condition
Density 15 Â°C (g/mL)   
Density 0 Â°C (g/mL)    
Density 5 Â°C (g/mL)    
Calculated API Gravity  
Viscosity at 15 Â°C (mPa.s) 
Viscosity at 0 Â°C (mPa.s)  
Viscosity at 5 Â°C (mPa.s)  
Surface tension 15 Â°C (oil - air)  
Interfacial tension 15 Â°C (oil - water)
```

Comment: What does df actually look like? Please provide a sample with a snippet of the relevant column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use capture groups with negative lookbehind:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([' 15 °', ' at 15 °', ' 0 °', ' at 0 °', ' 5 °', ' at 5 °'])
s = s.str.replace('(?<!at)\s+(15|0|5) °', r' at \1 °', regex=True)
print(s)
```

**Output**

```
0     at 15 °
1     at 15 °
2      at 0 °
3      at 0 °
4      at 5 °
5      at 5 °
dtype: object
```

As the `regex=True` indicates we are going to replace by using a regular expression, the pattern `(?<!at)\s+(15|0|5) °` means match a 15, 0, or 5 that does not has `at` (as the previous word) before it. The notation `(?<!at)` is known as a negative lookbehind, something like look at previous characters and see if they do not match something, in this case `at`.  The `(15|0|5)` is a capture group each capture group has a corresponding index, that you can use in the replacement pattern as in ' at \1 °'. So for example, the pattern will only replace a `15` that is not preceded by at, by `at 15`.

Comment: Can you breakdown what you did there please? I'd like to understand it better. WHat do "(?<!at)", "s+...", r', "\1" do?

Comment: @Mitch Updated the answer

Comment: What would "at \2 °" do for example? Much appreciated @Daniel

Comment: There is not second group, so it will probably error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using the RegEx flag, but you don't need it. `inplace` is the third argument and needs a boolean value, but you were putting `x` as the third argument, which is why it failed. You didn't use `%` formatting properly.

By complete coincidence, `inplace` can also be used to simplify the problem. You don't need to reassign in this case. Here's some nice(ish) code:

```py
for x in (0, 5, 15): # You were using range() wrong - this is correct
    df['Variable Name'].replace(' %s °' % x,' at %s °' % x, inplace=True)
    df['Variable Name'].replace(' at at %s °' % x,' at %s °' % x, inplace=True)
```

Try to avoid `%` formatting if you can use `.format()` and f-strings. But this should work.

Comment: Regex is exactly the way to go here

Comment: His original strings aren't RegEx, but yes, there are ways to do it with RegEx.

Comment: Regex would remove the unnecessary explicit loop and remove the assumption you're making about the possible numbers

Comment: I'm not saying there aren't ways to do it with RegEx; the best answer by Daniel Mesejo uses RegEx. But this is ONE way to do it given what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself from a `replace` with optional capture group:

```
s = pd.Series(['that at 15 °', 'this 15 °', 
               'that at 5 °', 'this 5 °', 
               'that at 0 °', 'this 0 °'])

for x in [0, 5, 15]:
    s = s.str.replace(f'((?: at)? {x} °)', f' at {x} °')
```

Output:

```
0    that at 15 °
1    this at 15 °
2     that at 5 °
3     this at 5 °
4     that at 0 °
5     this at 0 °
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

In single pass with *dict of regular expressions*:

```
In [113]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Variable Name'], data=[' 15 °', ' at at 15 °', ' 0 °', ' at at 0 °', '
     ...:  5 °', ' at at 5 °'])                                                                             

In [114]: df['Variable Name'].replace(regex={r'^\s*(\d+) °': r'at \1 °', r'at at (\d+) °': r' at \1 °'})    
Out[114]: 
0      at 15 °
1      at 15 °
2       at 0 °
3       at 0 °
4       at 5 °
5       at 5 °
Name: Variable Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the question. OP was trying to replace, eg `15 °` with `at 15 °`, but keep the existing `at 15 °` as is. That was the purpose for the second `replace`.